# getting error while converting datatable to Linq Query C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

this is my datatable(image attached). and i am trying to get Diffrent form by using Linq and in result featureid value is coming as getting System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator but in datatable Every Featureid row has a value

```
    var result1 = dtTaskandBugs.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["Storyid"])
                                .Select(item => new
                                {
                                    Storyid = item.Key,
                                    Assignedto = string.Join(",", item.Select(a => a["Assignedto"]).Distinct()),
                                    Featureid = item.Select(s => s["Featureid"]),
                                    Completed = item.Sum(y => Convert.ToInt64(y["Completed"])),
                                    effort = item.Sum(z => Convert.ToInt64(z["effort"]))
                                });
```

**ERROR**
Featureid value is 
 `{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<System.Data.DataRow, object>}`

> datatable before result

[image: datatable before result]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is caused by the fact you've left one lazy-evaluated column in select query result. While `string.Join` and `IEnumerable.Sum` produce value immediately, FeatureId is assigned a value of `IEnumerable` (because that's what `Select` returns). I believe that call to `ToList()` should solve the problem. 
I would also suggest using data model if possible.